# rpy2 no changes to dataframe after applying a function

Tags: python, rpy2

I try to do Box-Cox transformation in python with R code through rpy2 (yes, I know, that I can do Box-Cox transformation in Python, but I need exact results with the corresponding function in R).
I define a function

```
r_f = robjects.r('''
    ft <- function(sample) {
    sampleLambda=sample[,1:(ncol(sample))]
    preBox <- caret::preProcess(sample[,1:(ncol(sample))], method="BoxCox")
    pred <- stats::predict(preBox, sample[,1:(ncol(sample))])
    return(pred)
    } 
    ''')
```

Then, I try to apply the function (df is a pandas dataframe)

```
df2 = r_f(df)
```

But there is no changes. The same function written in R makes changes

Comment: Which version of rpy2 do you use?

Comment: I cannot reproduce with rpy2 version '3.0.3'. Please provide more details (a minimal dataframe + rpy2 version) and try with the newest version first. Good luck!

Comment: There is a fair bit of chance a different `sample` object is used between the function-written-in-R and that same function also written in R called from rpy2. The question is missing a complete example showing the issue.

Comment: I use 2.9 version